# error "a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have completed iPhone/iPad game. I am testing it in Xcode with developer provisioning certificate, and all is OK, but now I made a distribution certificate. When I am trying to test my game with distribution cert I get an error "a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found", and I could add my iPad to prov. profile only with developer cert. Could it be the problem for Apple Reviewers in future? Or I don't need distribution profile for debugging and testing?
I am sorry if you'll think I am noob. I am actually am. Please help me.

Thank for all of you. I got an answer for my question!

Comment: you cannot test your app on a device with an distribution certificate. User your developer provisioning certificate for testing on your device and a distribution certificate to submit the app to the store.

Comment: add a link to the documentation and that would be a great answer!

Comment: Use the distribution profile to create an ipa (a zip archive) and install that via itunes to the device. This is useful for remote installations. You need to have all UDIDs in your distrbution profile, tho. It's not for the AppStore.

Comment: @meccan Its not true, you can test your apps using the distribution profile. But as ott mentioned, you'll have to create a distribution profile for ad-hoc release, add the devices you want to test on and then build the code using this profile.